# How can I fit as many letters into as tight of a space as possible in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, lettering, workflow

I have a text which I outlined and broke into individual objects.

I want to fit this text into as tight a space as possible without overlapping, rotating or moving the letters around. The text doesn't need to be readable, it just needs to use the least amount of material as possible. How can I do something like this?

Comment: Not that I know of, you'll have to do it manually. If your text was not broken into outlines, you would simply adjust your kerning. Highlight the word, then `Alt` + `Left Arrow` to decrease, `Alt` + `Right Arrow` to increase.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a logo where a letter is made of particles of varying sizes?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13683/how-to-make-a-logo-where-a-letter-is-made-of-particles-of-varying-sizes)

Comment: I really don't understand this question - how can you make the letters fit tighter without moving them? If you *can* move them, and they're expanded so they're just shapes that happen to be in the shape of letters, I'd [use this method which stacks things with no overlap and no space in between](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19879/#19881), horizontally for letters then (if there's more than one line) group the lines and do it again vertically.

Comment: I think the poster simply wants the letters packed as tightly as possible so they can be plotted or CNC machined out of the minimal amount of material. Unfortunately you can't do this in Illu other than manually. Though if anyone knows of a plugin I would love to hear of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "auto-fit" features in Illustrator.

There have been a few users who have written scripts to fill something with a shape. In all these scripts a circle is the only shape which will work. There are issues with varying width and heights and collision detection. It's just not something Illustrator was designed to do, or does well.

I'm afraid, the best option is to manually fit your shapes into the container you want.

This question may be worth a look as well: [How to make a logo where a letter is made of particles of varying sizes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13683/how-to-make-a-logo-where-a-letter-is-made-of-particles-of-varying-sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

1. Keep the Shape on top and the outlined text on back of the shape,
2. Select Both Shape and text
3. Go to Illustrator <kbd>Menu > Object > Envelope Distort > Make with top Object</kbd>
4. You will get the result like text blends and fits in to the shape you asked to distort