# Adobe Illustrator CS6 Make a texture fit exacly in a custom shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, texture

I am trying to make this texture inside the penguin shape like this

[image]

Now i know i can use a clip mask like this

[image]

But i want to make it so the texture doesn't fall out of the shape, so the object follows the small patterns it now does this
[image]

is there anny way i can make this possible ?
Really hope someone can explain this to me.

The shapes are all vectors like
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If these are all single objects (as opposed to a pattern used to fill an area) the simplest way would be to put your penguin on a separate layer above the stitches and then lock the layer (using the little lock icon next to the eye in your layers palette).

Then, using your penguin form as a guide, simply select and delete the stitches at the edge which need deleting. Some which are mostly outside the penguin you'll probably delete while some which are only minimally outside you'll probably keep.
I think that's the best way to go at it, because you'll have to visually choose which stitches to keep or delete depending on how it affects the whole.

Then the rest of the stitches well outside can all be selected in large amounts by click and dragging over them to select them.

(If the stitches are all grouped then ungroup them by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, or alternatively use the white arrow tool to select them).

Comment: I did this already but i need to make it with allot of different shapes and vectors, isn't there a way just to colorise the knitting shapes with the image below and that illustrator knows to fill them completely instead of just half?, Like use the shape almost like a bucket filling tool ?

Comment: Hmm, right off the bat, I can't think of a way that would work. I'll give it a think, but ... .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no. Illustrator can not auto-fit one shape inside another.

If you only want whole petal shapes, you'll have to manually delete any half-shapes.

Related: [How can I fit as many letters into as tight of a space as possible in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/how-can-i-fit-as-many-letters-into-as-tight-of-a-space-as-possible-in-illustrato/21206#21206)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this while also looking for a something similar. This isn't the fix for me but it may be for you if you still need this for future projects...

http://vektorgarten.de/align-and-distribute-pathfinder.html

Comment: Hi Derek, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!