# How to form a shape with selective shapes in various size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

[image]

Basically my question is how to make this like the image that I uploaded. I know that you need to pick a shapes, and a picture of what whatever you would like to form into. Where can I buy or download that illustrator script?

Comment: Scott's answer here is also relevant: [**How can I fit as many letters into as tight of a space as possible in Illustrator**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21206/8708)

Answer (score -1):

You may check out below resources

Creating Repeating Patterns From Custom Shapes In Photoshop
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/repeating-patterns-from-custom-shapes/
http://99designs.com/designer-blog/2013/01/31/create-your-own-pattern-swatch-an-easy-5-step-illustrator-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

and this http://www.digitalartforall.com/648/scratch-creating-patterns-using-repeat/

Combine them. You will be able to get the results.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD. The best thing would be if you edit your first answer to include the second, rather than write an new answer.

Comment: It would also be better if you summarized the solution given in the links. In the case the linked sites go down your solution will still have some value.