# How to make letter shapes by filling in motifs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects

[image]How to make a shape by filling in motifs like the effect of the attached image? I know how to clip a pattern to a shape but this one is different. Thanks.

Comment: Illustrator: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/how-can-i-fit-as-many-letters-into-as-tight-of-a-space-as-possible-in-illustrato and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/how-can-i-fit-as-many-letters-into-as-tight-of-a-space-as-possible-in-illustrato -- it's even worse in Photoshop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibility in Photoshop is piece by piece with shape layers.

I think this is made in a vector program.

In Illustrator > **Pattern Brush**

[image: brush]

Once it's done copy/paste on Photoshop as a **Smart Object** and you can edit it back in Illustrator as many times as you want.

Comment: How can I fill in a shape like a heart shape (not just the edge of the shape) with this pattern effect? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Renae Did you try the search at the top of the page? There are many solutions for that.