# Best sources to learn Infographics designing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resource-recommendations, education, information-graphics, freelance

What is the best online sources to learn infographic designing from begining to master level?

Comment: check out this guide : https://venngage.com/blog/infographic-design/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools for making infographics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/tools-for-making-infographics)

Comment: https://piktochart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Piktochart-e-book-2-Create-Your-First-Infographic-In-15-Minutes.pdf here is one example